discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed
so I have a discord selfbot script, when I try to run it, I get an error like this.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 803, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 745, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

....
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Downloads\Compressed\tes\selfbot.py", line 88, in <module>
    bot.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 860, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 849, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 777, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 612, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 807, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.

Here's my full code:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import aiohttp
import asyncio

# Replace 'YOUR_DISCORD_TOKEN' with your actual user token
TOKEN = 'YOUR_DISCORD_TOKEN'
# Replace 'YOUR_CHANNEL_ID' with the ID of your designated channel in your server
MY_CHANNEL_ID = 'YOUR_CHANNEL_ID'

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
intents.guilds = True
intents.message_content = True  # This intent is needed to read message content

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', self_bot=True, intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user}')

async def process_message(message):
    # Ignore messages sent by the bot itself
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    # Check if the message has attachments
    if message.attachments:
        for attachment in message.attachments:
            # Ensure the attachment is an image
            if attachment.content_type and attachment.content_type.startswith('image'):
                try:
                    # Retry logic for downloading the image
                    image_data = None
                    for attempt in range(3):
                        try:
                            # Download the image asynchronously
                            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                                async with session.get(attachment.url) as response:
                                    image_data = await response.read()
                            break  # Exit retry loop if successful
                        except aiohttp.ClientConnectorError as e:
                            print(f'Error downloading image: {str(e)}. Retrying...')
                            await asyncio.sleep(5)  # Wait before retrying
                    else:
                        print(f'Failed to download image after 3 attempts. Skipping...')
                        return

                    # Check if the image contains a QR code
                    if image_data and has_qr_code(image_data):
                        # Decode the image asynchronously
                        decoded_urls = await decode_image(image_data)

                        # Send the decoded URLs to your designated channel with a note about the source server and channel
                        channel = bot.get_channel(MY_CHANNEL_ID)
                        for decoded_url in decoded_urls:
                            note = f'Decoded URL from {message.author.name} in #{message.channel.name} ({message.guild.name}):'
                            await channel.send(f'{note} {decoded_url}')
                    else:
                        # Print that the image does not contain a QR code
                        note = f'Image from {message.author.name} in #{message.channel.name} ({message.guild.name}) does not contain a QR code.'
                        print(note)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f'Error processing image: {str(e)}')

def has_qr_code(image_data):
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(image_data))
    decoded_objects = decode(img)
    return bool(decoded_objects)

async def decode_image(image_data):
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(image_data))
    decoded_objects = decode(img)
    decoded_urls = [obj.data.decode("utf-8") for obj in decoded_objects]
    return decoded_urls

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    try:
        await process_message(message)
        await bot.process_commands(message)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error: {str(e)}')

bot.run(TOKEN)

I tried to change the token account and still got the error.
And I also tried using another account token and got the same error.

Discord does not allow "selfbots", you cannot use an user token for your bot. Instead, create a Bot in the Discord Developer Portal to get a valid token.

Pretty sure you are passing in a wrong token (missing or having an extra a letter, etc.) to the TOKEN variable.
Try regenerating your token by going to the discord developer portal and clicking on your bot, then click on "Bot" and "Reset Token" on the right. Pass the verification and copy the token generated, then paste that into your program and try again.
